# MicroSoft R open Package install issue

Tags: r

I'm getting this error when trying to install or load packages on MRO..

> Warning: unable to access index for repository
>   https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-11-01/src/contrib: 
>   cannot open URL
>   'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-11-01/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Does anyone know what to do..?

Paul.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: nothing on there seemed to help..?

Comment: I get this error as soon as i click on Install to get the Install Packages window on R studio...before I even attempt to search or install..?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with MRAN. I'll notify the team.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use CRAN to install packages; you'll just get the most recent versions rather than the snapshotted ones.

Comment: I've had some issues with the MRAN repositories before that are like this; the site will go dark for hours. But it's never been down for more than 2, so I would try again now.

Comment: The Time Machine is broken: https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/timemachine/

Comment: It should be working now.